# Trig. identity question

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if $-(r^2\sin^2{\theta}+r^3\cos^2{\theta}) = -r^2-r^3$. If not, how would you simply the above function?

Thank you.

Comment: The two expressions are not equal. The expression $-(r^2\sin^2\theta+r^3\cos^2\theta$) looks simple already. For certain purposes you might want to replace $\sin^2\theta$ by $1-\cos^2\theta$, or $\cos^2\theta$ by $1-\sin^2\theta$. It all depends on what sort of question you want to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The identity you are thinking of is $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$.  In the above, we cannot take advantage of this identity since, if we factor out an $r^2$, we are still left with an $r$ attached to the $\sin^2(\theta)$.  The best you can really do is apply $\cos^2(\theta) = 1-\sin^2(\theta)$.  We will get the following:

$$-(r^2\sin^2(\theta) + r^3\cos^2(\theta)) = -r^2\sin^2(\theta)-r^3+r^3\sin^2(\theta) = (r^3-r^2)\sin^2(\theta)-r^2$$

Unfortunately, this doesn't really simplify any further.

Answer (score 0):

No, because if $\theta=0$, this becomes $-r^3$. If $r=2$ (say), this certainly isn't equal to $-r^2-r^3$; $-r^3= -8$ while $-r^2-r^3=-12$.